# How to prevent stored XSS from javascript and html injection

Tags: asp.net, xss

We have `asp.net` application developed using `.net framework 4.0` and we have form lets say `dataentry.aspx` where users enter value in `textbox` and that value will be stored in the database. We implemented database connection logic and everything in code behind. All are working good.

While testing the tester is using fiddler and appending the `javascript` or `html` payload, which is getting saved in the database and it is giving alert which fetching and displaying it on the `UI`.

Lets say user enters welcome in the `textbox` but in the fiddler we are appending script payload like

```
welcome %uff1cscript%uff1ealert(XSS);%uff1c/script%uff1e
```

So what we did is that before saving it into `textbox` we are encoding the above payload and saving it into the `database`. While displaying we are decoding it and show it on the UI.

So, In the UI it shows `welcome<script>alert(xss)</script>` and it is not showing any alert since we are doing encoding and decoding.

But we don't want to show the injected value.

We have some questions:

- Is it possible to discard the request if it is modified by the fiddler? If yes how can we check whether the request payload is modified or not?
- We want to redirect it to error page if the script payload is injected with actual payload because we don't want to save that in database.
- Is it possible to validate whether injection happened or not in the code behind.
- How can we check whether the text has `html` and `javascript`. Is there any regular expression available to validate the text has `javascipt` or `html`

Comment: I don't think you can really avoid showing the injected value. It's the user's problem if the malicious values they entered are returned as nonsense. Your application has already done its job by preventing the code from being executed

Comment: P.s. to stop the request being modified by something like Fiddler then using HTTPS would help. And anyway it should not matter because you should have server side validation to defeat any attempts at sending a corrupted request.

Comment: I don't think you could easily tell if the request came directly from the browser or was modified on the way, but again it's not hugely relevant. Either the request is invalid or it's not.

Comment: The only way I can think of to try and detect injection values would be to detect a `<script>` tag, and the equivalent closing tag, and then remove that plus everything else in between the tags. But a) it's relatively computationally expensive to examine every string which comes in to your application in this way and b) that's only a simplistic way of injecting script...there are more sophisticated ways which string matching would struggle to detect